# How do I correctly control stacking ordered of my divs using z-index?

Tags: html, css

I have a drop down menu (#dropDownMenu) which appears when the "#headerNav" of my website is hovered over. It works properly if I position the #dropDownMenu (originally hidden with display:none until link is hovered over) slightly over the #headerNav div.

This stops the slight flickering that is caused if the cursor isn't moved over fast enough to the drop down menu when it appears. By slightly overlapping #dropDownMenu over #headerNav this makes it seem like the #headerNav is still being hovered over when cursor is actually in the #dropDownMenu.

Anyway I now want to hide the overlapping part of #dropDownMenu behind header or #headerContent so everything looks neater and so the drop down menu actually looks like it's appearing beneath the #headerNav.

I've tried different z-index settings and none seem to work which is quite annoying. When I set the z-index of #headerNav:hover #dropDownMenu to -1 it is hidden behind all content as expected.

If I set z-index of header or #headerContent to a number higher than "#headerNav:hover #dropDownMenu" then hover over #headerNav there is no difference. I can still see #dropDownMenu overlapping.

**CSS:**

```
header {

    position:fixed; 
    top:0;
    right:0;
    left:0;
    height: 40px;
    z-index:20;
    }

    #headerContent {
    background-color: $main-background-color;
    width: $site-width;
    margin:0px auto 0px auto;
    height:40px;

    }

    #headerNav {
    float:right;
    height:37px;
    width:auto;
    margin-top:1px;
    background-color:#464646;
    color:#cccccc;
    }

    #headerNav:hover {
    background-color:#626262;
    cursor:pointer;
    color: white;
    }

    #headerNav:hover #dropDownMenu {
    position:absolute;
    background-color:white;
    border:1px solid gray;
    top:35px;
    right:-39px;
    height:300px;
    width:200px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:gray;
    display:block !important;
    z-index:1;
    }

    ul li { 
    float:right;
    }

    #photoThumbnail img {
    height:28px;
    width:31px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-right:8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px 12px 1px 12px;
    border-radius: 1px 12px 1px 12px;

    }

    #currentUser {
    position:relative;
    padding-top:12px;
    padding-left:12px;
    padding-right:6px;
    }


    #siteNavigation {
    display:none;

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <div id='headerContent'>
    <div id='LogoHolder'>
    </div>
    <nav id='headerNav'>
      <ul>
        <li id='photoThumbnail'></li>
        <li id='currentUser'>
          <ul id='dropDownMenu'>
            <li>link1</li>
            <li>link2</li>
            <li>link3</li>
            <li>link4</li>
            <li>link5</li>
            <li>link6</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Examples and corrections will be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your z-index setting is being ignored you might need to add position property, set it to relative or whatever it needs to be. I'm pretty sure z-index is ignored if position property is not set.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find that you are trying to hack your way around a fundamental markup issue. THe usual way to do ul based drop downs is this

```
<ul id='headerNav'>
    <li>Menu Title
        <ul class='dropDownMenu>
            <li>link1</li>
            <li>link2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This way you set the hover action on #headerNav li:hover and your drop down is a child of your hover element and the menu will stay open (and not flicker) when you move your mouse over the .dropDownMenu as it is also being hovered. You're close.. you just need to wrap your html a bit better and adjust your css to hover on the li and show and hide the "li ul.dropDownMenu"

This should get rid of the need for your overlap - and fix your problem.

Comment: That is the exact setup I have. I converted the HAML to html and updated my question. Also it wouldn't be a problem if iI was using drop down menu where I didn't need to resize the width. Resizing the width messes up other things and this is why I had to use absolute positioning.